# What is it even called? "Weighted rate of occurrence?" "Weighted rates"?

Tags: weights

I know so little about this subject, that I'm not even sure what to call it.

Lets say I have a giant list of machines in a factory.  Some get used frequently, others not so much.  I want to calculate a break rate for each machine.  that's easy enough.  so I divide the number of times it broke, by the number of times it was used.

However, that's not really intuitive, as a machine could have a 100% break rate by being used once and breaking once.  I'd like to see the machines that get used hundreds of times, AND have high break rates, as more important than a machine that gets used once.

Is there a statistically sound method of "weighting" a rate by the number of underlying occurrences of the denominator?  (number of times it was used)?

Again, apologies for my ignorance.  I wish I knew what to even google.

Answer (score 0):

Every time a machine is used it can break down or not. Assuming that every run is indipendent we could use the binomial distribution to calculate the confidence intervalls for the break down rate of every machine.

Let's consider two examples. Machine a broke down after 50 times being used and machine b broke down at the very first time. The confidence intervalls are:

```
prop.test(1, 50)
95 percent confidence interval:
0.001044888 0.120108120

prop.test(1, 1)
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.05462076 1.00000000
```

As you can see the confidence intervalls are pretty broad for the machine that broke down at first time. If you want to be sure to have a machine that does not break down fast you should look for the machine that has the lowest upper confidence intervall.

Further, if the machines get repaired they can break multiple time. Again, assuming every run is independent, you can still use the binomial distribution to estimate confidence intervalls. The code above is produced with R. The do it by hand you can have a look [here](https://sigmazone.com/binomial-confidence-intervals/).

But to be honest I am not sure how reasonable it is to assume independency of the trials here. Maybe somehow calculating confidence intervalls of survival times for each machine is possible.

Comment: I used machines breaking as an easy example, but this will actually be used on "repeat" discrepancy rates.  (where each discrepancy is a "use", and each repeat is a "break") By independence definition (that I just looked up), I think you're right.  i dont know if we can assume independence.  if the training level of the operator is different, if certain repairs were accomplished, if prior knowledge exists....all of that may affect the probability of a repeat discrepancy.  But you provided some researchable terms.  I'll go down that rabbit hole and see what i find.  thank you for the response!